# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'postList'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

just tomorrow try coding on TypeScript with React,  and some stuff not undertand, i will be happy if someone help me

structure: i have parent app , he use children component post-list etc.

```
//app.js
import PostList from '../post-list/post-list';
function App() {
    return (
            <Container>
                 <GlobalStyle />

                <Header>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </Header>

                <main>
                   **<PostList />** *//here webstorm tell me this error*
                </main>
            </Container>
    );
}
```

```
 //post-list.js

interface postInterface {
    id: number
    title: string
    body: string
}

type postList = [postInterface];


const PostList = (posts: postList)=>{

    if (!posts) {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    }

    const items = posts.map((post, index) => <Post key={index} {...post}/>);

    return(
        <PostListView>
            {items}
        </PostListView>
    )

};


export default PostList;

PostList.getInitialProps = async ()=>{
  const posts = await service.getAllPosts();
  return {posts}
};
```

[ error ] ERROR in G:/WORK/Projects/blog-app/src/components/app/app.tsx(16,23):
16:23 Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'postList'.
    14 | 
    15 |

> 16 |                     
>          |                       ^
>       17 |

Comment: From `(posts: postList)` it seems like `posts` is the mandatory argument for this component which you are not passing from your parent component. Mind checking this once ?

Answer (score 0):

What type is returned by this call?

```
  const posts = await service.getAllPosts();
```

It looks like the return type of that function does not match the input signature of your component.

Comment: array of objects , 

but anyway error in component up not in post-list.tsx, error in app.tsx
i think TS requires parameters  in parent component,  but i fetching props like example from next.js

Answer (score -1):

You forgot these `{}`

```
const PostList = ({posts: postList})=>{
```

because React component expects an `object` of `props`, instead you were passing a `postList` var

Comment: No thats incorrect. This is a component which can either by a class or function.

Comment: If you use this <PostList /> TypeScript expects a props object passing to the function.
He should use {posts?: postList} also to make posts optional since he is not passing any posts at all to the component

Comment: Yup it does but you don't need `{}` around the argument.

Comment: Yeah about your second point, I commented the same in the comment section of the question.

Comment: i know  сonpоnents this just like functions or classes,  and when we  in jsx <PostList posts={posts}> this like parameters functions 


but i use nextjs  and,  in doc fetching data this pattern
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps 

from parrent i nothing send to  <PostList /> 
this need just start and all , like analogy 
function postList  ()=>{...};
and  now need start him postList(); === <PostList/>